# Todo and rmd-generated LaTeX document

Tags: r, markdown

How to use the `todo` package in R Markdown-generated LaTeX documents?

To load packages, it is possible to add them to the document's header with `header-includes:`. This successfully works with `\usepackage{hyperref}` and its styling (`\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}`), but doesn't seem to allow to add inline `todo{}`s.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Test"
date: "7/24/2017"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{todo}
   - \usepackage{hyperref}
   - \hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
---

[Link styling works](www.example.com) but \todo{todo does not}.
```

which generates

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want  to use really the package `todonotes`?

Comment: Anyway the problem is not related in with Rmarkdow but with the `todo` package,  that do not make the automatic internal `\label{todolbl:1}` .

Comment: @Fran Any workaround?

Comment: Look like a bug of the package, but you can insert the `\label{todolbl:1}`, `\label{todolbl:1}`, etc.   manually. But  what I would do is just change  "todo" by "todonotes" in the YAML header and add  `\listoftodos`  at the end of the .Rmd file.

Comment: @Fran Yes, this seems a good solution (answer) to me

Comment: Then I add  an example as answer to  remove this question of the unanswered list.

Answer (score 4):

A good alternative is use the `\todo` command but from the  `todonotes` package. Example:

[image: mwe]

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Test"
date: "7/24/2017"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
   - \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue!30!black}
   - \geometry{rmargin=1.5in} 
---
[Link styling works](www.example.com)
\todo{Without load \texttt{hyperref} yourself!} 
as well as margin notes (but add some space to the right margin!)  
\todo[color=green!50,inline]{... or use  \texttt{todonotes} inline}.
\listoftodos
```